# How to access an interface from a typescript.d.ts file when the module names conflict?

Tags: dojo, typescript, amd

How can I access the i1 from within esri.dijit?

```
module dijit {
    interface i1 {};
}

module esri {
    module dijit {
        interface i2 {}
        interface i3 extends dijit.i2, dijit.i1 {}
    }
}
```

See [Playground example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground/#src=module%20dijit%20%7B%0A%09interface%20i1%20%7B%7D;%0A%7D%0A%0Amodule%20esri%20%7B%0A%09module%20dijit%20%7B%0A%09%09interface%20i2%20%7B%7D%0A%09%09interface%20i3%20extends%20dijit.i2,%20dijit.i1%20%7B%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%7D%0A).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things. First you need to export an interface for it to be usable outside the module so:

```
module dijit {
    export interface i1 {};
}
```

Secondly if you are going to use the same name locally the global name `dijit` is going to be shadowed. So you need to create an alias :

```
module dijit {
    export interface i1 {};
}
import alias = dijit;
```

Now your complete code:

```
module dijit {
    export interface i1 {};
}
import alias = dijit;

module esri {   
    module dijit {
        export interface i2 {}
        interface i3 extends dijit.i2, alias.i1 {}
    }
}
```